# On C++ Boost Graph Creation With Bundled Properties

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I am trying to set up a Boost Graph of vertices with bundled properties. Unfortunately, the "add_edge" step doesn't seem to work resulting in the following error. Any insights would be helpful!

`error: constructor for 'boost::detail::adj_list_gen<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, Node,boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, Node, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config::rand_stored_vertex'
      must explicitly initialize the member 'm_property' which does not have a default constructor
          rand_stored_vertex() { }`

and a series of other such statements culminating in the following:

`in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::add_edge<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, Node, boost::no_property,boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::adj_list_gen<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, Node, boost::no_property, boost::no_property,boost::listS>, boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, Node, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config,boost::undirected_graph_helper<boost::detail::adj_list_gen<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, Node, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>,boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, Node, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config> >' requested here
                boost::add_edge( svlist[0], svlist[1], SG );`

```
class Node {
public: 
  std::string id;
  Node(int a) {
    id = std::to_string(a);
  } 
};

std::vector<Node> nodelist;
Node n1(1);
Node n2(2);
Node n3(3);
Node n4(4);
nodelist.push_back(n1);
nodelist.push_back(n2);
nodelist.push_back(n2);
nodelist.push_back(n4);

typedef boost::adjacency_list< boost::vecS, boost::vecS, 
                                      boost::undirectedS, Node> ScafGraph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<ScafGraph>::vertex_descriptor SV;
typedef boost::graph_traits<ScafGraph>::edge_descriptor SE;

ScafGraph SG;

std::vector<SV> svlist;
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    SV v = boost::add_vertex( nodelist[i], SG );
    svlist.push_back(v);
}

SE e; bool ok;
boost::tie(e, ok) = boost::edge( svlist[0], svlist[1], SG );
if(!ok) {
    boost::add_edge( svlist[0], svlist[1], SG );
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what the line "boost::tie ..." does.  What happens if you comment it out?

Comment: @ravenspoint The boost::tie(e,ok) call is to check if any errors can occur during the addition of a new edge (for example, when already present). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors in the `Node` class. Tested in GCC 4.9.0 with C++11 in Windows.

```
class Node {
public:
    std::string id;
    Node(int a) { id = std::to_string(a); }
    Node() = default;
};
```

- The parenthesis after `Node` are wrong.
- The constructor that receive an `int` and is converted to string, in the conversion the parameter `was not used`.
- Adding a `vertex` or a `edge` to a graph when you are using `vecS` require that the Node used has default constructor, because the vector could need to grow and reallocate the elements, when it grow the elements are default constructed. In the case of your custom Node, don't have default constructor.

Comment: Thanks! I had made a mistake while copying the code; removed the braces. But the default constructor was the issue.

Comment: The default constructor fixed for me. Thanks